# Tkinter isn't working with Pycharm

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I was running this code and it is supposed to be creating a window but it doesn't create any window in Pycharm. I am using Pycharm Community edition with Python 3.6. When I am running this code in IDLE, the window is generated.

```
import tkinter

from datetime import date, datetime

root = tkinter.Tk()

c = tkinter.Canvas(root,width =800, height =768, bg = 'black')
c.pack()

c.create_text(100,50, anchor = 'w', fill = 'orange', \
              font = 'Arial 28 bold underline', text = 'My Countdown calendar')
```

Comment: Is there some sort of execute command? Something like: sys.exit(app.exec_())?

Comment: Simply start loop at end: `root.mainloop()`

Comment: For any other that this is not your problem, make sure that the python file is not called `tkinter.py`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regular python shell and IDLE supports using tk without a mainloop. This is done by several hooks, installed when a tkapp object is being initialized, which handles Tk events while the shell is waiting for user input. However pycharm does not support this. So inorder to diplay your window using pycharm, you have to call

```
root.mainloop()
```

at the end.